# Does the too many request exception effect the other users

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have come across too many request exception in my application so I limited the number of requests to adjust them in the correct way. What I would like to know that if a user starts 10 requests at time and other user starts 10 requests at time and the limit is 19. will this exception happen even if the requests are sent from the same server that host the application. How is it possible if this is the case to allow each user to send requests individually even if they are sent from the same server.

Comment: Are you asking about client-side or server-side? Where and how did you limit the number of requests? Are your users using a webbrowser? An App?

Comment: I have an application coded in asp.net what I am asking is that when the server process these requests from the server side will each request made by different users using different browsers effect the overall limit of the requests and causes the application to throw exception or will be handled differently

Comment: The requests are made from the server side to another server using httpwebrequest

Comment: Are you getting too many requests error from the other server?

Comment: Yes I was getting too many request but I resolved that issue by reducing the number of requests but what I would like to find out is that if multiple instances start at the same time and go above the limit number by adding each requests from each instance will the server throw too many requests in this case